# EMPTY $dbh->get_results($query) IN WORDPRESS

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm executing that code in a Wordpress. The wordpress is working fine, the query in the phpmyadmin is returning results. But `$sets` is empty. 
All the other things in wordpress is working fine.

```
global $wpdb; echo DB_NAME; echo DB_PASSWORD; ECHO DB_HOST;
$dbh = new wpdb(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);
$table = "dp";  
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT(id_set) FROM $table WHERE id_producto = ".$idproducto;
$sets = $dbh->get_results($query);var_dump($dbh);
if (isset($sets)) return $sets;
else return false;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe there is no return? What are the expected returns? From wordpress code and from phpmyadmin?

Comment: wp codex: "Methods in the wpdb() class should not be called directly. Use the global $wpdb object instead!"  do not create new instance of wpdb, globalize @wpdb then use $wpdb->query()

Comment: @MichalS THANKS! This works for me. I've used it before this way, but this is a code from someone else, and I didn't realised.

Comment: glad I was able to help and you solved it.